# Dynamic IN+IF clause with GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am filtering buyers (many) for a given property (one) with the main condition of

- if the buyer requires specific exact # of bathrooms (`buyers.bathroom_exact='1'`), match it to the property's bathroom value.

Buyers can select multiple exact bathroom matches. Here's a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `buyers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `bathroomreq` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `buyers_bathrooms` (
  `buyer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `number` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `buyers` ( name, bathroomreq ) VALUES ( 'John Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO `buyers` ( name, bathroomreq ) VALUES ( 'John Smith', 1);

INSERT INTO buyers_bathrooms ( buyer_id, number ) VALUES ( 1, 8 );
INSERT INTO buyers_bathrooms ( buyer_id, number ) VALUES ( 1, 9 );
INSERT INTO buyers_bathrooms ( buyer_id, number ) VALUES ( 1, 10 );
INSERT INTO buyers_bathrooms ( buyer_id, number ) VALUES ( 2, 5 );
```

The only way I can think of doing this is using a column which has an `IF` clause to see if the bathroomreq is `1`, then match the group_concat of the buyers specified bathrooms:

```
SELECT IF ( bathroomreq = '1', 8 IN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(number) AS bathrooms
    FROM buyers_bathrooms
    WHERE buyers.id = buyers_bathrooms.buyer_id 
) , 1 ) AS bathroom_match,

bathroomreq,

id, name

FROM buyers
```

So this property basically has 8 bathrooms and that's why 8 is hardcoded in there.

Here's a mysql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/508cc/1

Is this the only way of solving the problem and is it reliable? Can I do it an alternative way with something like a dynamic `INNER JOIN` if `bathroomreq` is `1`? Basically, can I avoid having to branch based on `bathroom_match` in my application code and filter this elegantly through SQL alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with an `exists` clause:

```
select b.bathroomreq, b.id, b.name,
       (b.bathroomreq <> 1 or
        exists (select 1
                from buyers_bathrooms bb
                where bb.buyer_id = b.id and bb.number = 8
               )
       ) as bathroom_match
from buyers b;
```

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't word everything right. Is there a way so that I don't even have to use a `bathroom_match` field at all? I.E. John Smith doesn't even get returned in the results using the sample fiddle above? Thanks!